# AngularJS: Using class and ng-class in the same element and other unsuccessful attempts

Tags: angularjs

I have the div below which HAS to have the frmBar class assigned and also a second class depending on the value of Request_Type (SAP - clr-purple, WEB - clr-darkblue, and three others).

When I try either of the following, neither class is assigned.

```
<div ng-class="{frmBar SAP:'clr-purple', Web:'clr-darkblue'}[myrequest.request_type]">

<div ng-class="{SAP:'frmBar clr-purple', Web:'frmBar clr-darkblue'}[myrequest.request_type]">
```

This one applies frmBar but not the ng-class:

```
<div class="frmBar" ng-class="{SAP:'clr-purple', Web:'clr-darkblue'}[myrequest.request_type]">
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-class`'s object form takes an object where the keys are the class names and the values are boolean expressions that say whether to apply that class.

```
<div class="frmBar" ng-class="{SAP: myrequest.request_type == 'SAP', Web: myrequest.request_type == 'Web'}">
```

The values of the object can be scope values, so you could, for instance, have:

```
app.myController = function($scope) {
  $scope.isSAP = function() {
    return $scope.myrequest.request_type == 'SAP';
  };

  $scope.isWeb = function() {
    return $scope.myrequest.request_type == 'Web';
  };
}
```

and

```
<div class="frmBar" ng-class="{SAP: isSAP(), Web: isWeb()}">
```

Comment: wouldn't changing it in the controller affect the ng-model in the form? The reason I am trying to do it in the html is because this is just for styling and the value might be changed in the form.  Also, I tried your html code and it is still just applying frmBar

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "changing it in the controller." Since the code from the question only had a bit of HTML, I made something up--but you can use *any* scope value from the controller you want (e.g. you can set boolean properties when it first loads, etc.) Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/GX4AL/

Comment: OK. I see you're not changing the model because Request_Type can still be changed. Your creating new scope variables to style ... now that it makes sense to me, I'll try that way because the inline isn't working (I was using this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/GX4AL/) and it worked for him ... damn!

Comment: It's a little verbose, but here's an example of how you would do it with the boolean expressions inline: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/8by93/

Comment: Well, when the controller way didn't work, I tried your latter verbose inline method and that doesn't work for me either. I suspect something ELSE may be preventing this from working so I created a fiddle with my exact css and code - http://jsfiddle.net/wynnwade/vsjVD/

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/Ls3e2/ (1) The JS in the controller was not valid; (2) Object keys with dashes in them need to be quoted.

Comment: LOL that shouldn't have been that difficult ... AngularJS is so powerful and so absolutely wonderful and fun but it is also SOOOO vast and difficult to learn quickly